# Check if a record exists in a Cassandra table using the Python driver

Tags: python, cassandra

How can be determined whether a record exists in a table? The way I tried was to do a `SELECT` query and then count the rows of the `ResultSet` using the following:

```
rows = session.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id=%s", ([<id_here>]))
if len(rows) == 0:
    print "Does not exist"
```

However, `ResultSet` does not support `len`. In another answer, they suggest to use `SELECT COUNT(*)` which in another reference is strongly discouraged. Is there a more standard way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply do one of the following:

```
rows = session.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id=%s", ([<id_here>]))
if not rows:
    print "Does not exist"
```

Or, if selecting multiple rows you could iterate over the ResultSet with:

```
for row in rows:
    do_something(row)
```

ResultSet also has a current_rows attribute which will be empty if none were returned.

See http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.ResultSet for more details on how to use the ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra `session.execute` returns `ResultSet` object that contain `current_rows` attribute.

try folowing:

```
    r = session.execute(f"SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE id = {some_id} limit 1")
    if(len(r.current_rows) == 0):
        # your code here
```