# Check if Cassandra's resultSet is empty or not (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, cassandra, datastax

I am running something like this

```
    def searchCassanadra(self):
    # Iterate over every pokemon
    for x in self.pokemon_list:
        # Query
        query = session.execute("SELECT pokemon_id FROM ds_pokedex.pokemon where pokemon_id=" + repr(x))
```

The above code is returning me `<class 'cassandra.cluster.ResultSet'>`

How can I check if this `ResultSet` is empty or filled from the Cassandra?

I am coding in the python.
Sorry for the newbie question.

If I try to do the

```
         if query.current_rows:
            print 'y'
        else:
            print 'n'
```

I am getting this error

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946458/check-if-a-record-exists-in-a-cassandra-table-using-the-python-driver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a record exists in a Cassandra table using the Python driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946458/check-if-a-record-exists-in-a-cassandra-table-using-the-python-driver)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `query._current_rows` attribute is a pandas DataFrame, so when you try to run `query.current_rows` a ValueError will always be raised, regardless of whether the `ResultSet` is empty or not.

From the [Cassandra Driver docs](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/_modules/cassandra/cluster.html#ResultSet) for `ResultSet`, we see that the `current_rows` function looks for the existence of a `_current_rows` attribute:

```
@property
def current_rows(self):
    """
    The list of current page rows. May be empty if the result was empty,
    or this is the last page.
    """
    return self._current_rows or []
```

If `self._current_rows` above is a pandas DataFrame, this will always return a ValueError. For example:

```
>>> data = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
>>> df or []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/src/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df or []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/src/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Therefore, to check whether the pandas DataFrame in a `ResultSet` contains data, you can do something like this:

```
if not query._current_rows.empty:
        print 'y'
    else:
        print 'n'
```

(Note: I don't know what your `session.row_factory` looks like, but I am assuming it is creating a pandas DataFrame from the rows returned by Cassandra, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484806/7373512) answer)